# Git - comparing folder with git repository of the same folder

Tags: git

I have a zip file that contains a Ruby on Rails project.  I also have the full Git repository of this same Ruby on Rails project.  The zip file is essentially an orphaned topic branch of the full git repository.  If it were properly included in the Git repository, it would have diverged from master several revisions behind the current master's HEAD revision.  Unfortunately for me, the zip file does not contain a Git repository and is just the flat files leaving me having to audit the zip file for changes.  Needless to say, this is rather tedious so while I work on that I am hoping that SO can help me with a better way to solve this problem!

What I'm asking help with is this:

Is there a way to compare a folder that is not a git repository with a folder that is under git's control?  Remember, the directories are both Ruby on Rails projects of the *same* project, just one is in Git and the other is not, so it lacks all of the historical context in which to easily base a merge off of.

I've already tried pasting the zip file contents on top of my project's main directory and inspecting the differences that way.  This just deletes almost 1.5 months of work, which produces a git diff with tons of deletions and potential regressions.  Perhaps there is a way to determine from this information when the zip file diverged from master and create a branch that diverges from that commit?  Then I could merge or rebase just the relevant changes, without worrying about the changes I've made that I need to keep.

Either way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: `git clone` and `diff` the cloned repo against the non-controlled dir.

A more complex solution could involve bringing the non-controlled repo into a separate branch and doing a merge.

Answer (score 1):

I ended finding a way to resolve this myself.

I ran `git init` on the unzipped folder, added and committed all the files and created an "initial commit".  Then I setup my project folder repository as a remote for the new git repository.  This let me merge the new code on top of the orphaned code: `git merge local/HEAD master`.  Once I had completed the merge and dealt with the conflicts, I was ready to run this process in reverse.

I added a remote to my project directory pointing to the zip folder git repository, and merged the tip revision there into a topic branch.  `git merge orphaned_directory/HEAD orphaned_code_branch`.  I dealt again with the conflicts, being careful not to introduce regressions.

After this was done, voila.  Tests pass and code integrated.  Thank everyone for helping me brainstorm this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to manually pick a range of commits that might have been the fork point (guess based on date range), and then programmatically diff against them, and pick the commit that produces the fewest amount of diffs.

```
git checkout --orphan zip_extract
git rm -rf .
```

Unzip, git add --all, git commit

You would then need to script something up that did

```
for sha in ($git rev-list OLDEST_POTENTIAL_SHA..NEWEST_POTENTIAL_SHA)
do
   git diff [options] ${sha} zip_extract | analysis_script
done
```

You could experiment with certain stat options to git diff and pipe to awk, or you could just dump out the full diff and pipe to wc -l.

Optimistically one of them will jump out as being more right than the others.  You would then branch from that point and extract to there (or merge in from the orphan branch) and then attempt to merge that to master.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [**git bisect ??**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect). That will help you to find the commit you are looking for. In your repo start bisect from HEAD to some commit for which you are sure it is there in non git folder.

after each bisect you can **see how many files are different**(using some directory compare utility) and **mark that bisect as either good or bad**.
and **you can zero upon the commit** from where your git repo got diverged.
Sample commands will be like this

```
git bisect start HEAD some_old_commit_id
git bisect bad
git bisect good
git bisect bad
```